# Order by field not working,but no error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this,

```
select * from my_table where `status`='1' ORDER BY FIELD(city_id,548) ASC;
```

My purpose is to show all records from the table, but records with `city_id=548` should come first.

Currently its showing all records but no desired sorting! Any ideas?

Comment: Provide some sample data, and what is the datatype of city_id ?

Comment: Change `asc` to `desc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is working but you need to change it to `DESC` because `FIELD()` returns the `index` of the value in the parameter.

Other than `FIELD()` which accepts multiple parameters, you can alternatively use `=` if you only have one condition.

```
ORDER BY (city_id = 548) DESC
```

when `city_id = 548` is `true`, it returns `1` otherwise `0` that is why we used `DESC`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

descending order in sql is denoted by `DESC` keyword I think other values are smaller than 548 that's why it's not work as you expect

```
select * from my_table where `status`='1' ORDER BY FIELD(city_id,548) DESC;
```